# How to use MINUS operator in SQL?

Tags: php, sql

I want to retrieve all the details of bookings table which didn’t make the payment. I have used MINUS operator. But it didn’t work. It gives SQL Error. How to get bookingid which doesn’t exist in payments table.

This is my code.

```
$SQL ="SELECT bookingid FROM bookings WHERE checkindate >= '$new_date_in' AND checkoutdate <= '$new_date_out' MINUS  SELECT bookingid FROM payments ";
        $run=mysql_query($SQL,$con) or die ("SQL error");
```

----$new_date_in and $new_date_out are user selected start and end dates---

[Bookings Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/75cMg.jpg)

[payments table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KN5s7.jpg)

Comment: What DB is this, specifically? And what is your error, specifically?

Comment: `MINUS` is product specific, but perhaps not for MySQL? ANSI SQL has `EXCEPT`.

Comment: mysql doesn't have a minus operator. there's `not in(...)` as an alternative

Comment: php Myadmin .It shows this statment is incorrect. This comes ("SQL error")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `not exists` or `not in`:

```
SELECT b.bookingid
FROM bookings b
WHERE b.checkindate >= '$new_date_in' AND
      b.checkoutdate <= '$new_date_out' AND
      b.bookingid NOT IN (SELECT bookingid FROM payments);
```

This also gives you the opportunity to get other fields from `bookings`.

Also, you should use parameters in the query rather than stuffing them in the query string.

Answer (score 1):

Indeed MINUS is not in mysql.

you query is fairly simple, but I would avoid a solution with NOT IN because it's not optimal at all if there's a lot of records in your payments table.

I would advise the use of NOT EXISTS

```
SELECT b.bookingid FROM bookings b 
WHERE checkindate >= '$new_date_in' 
  AND checkoutdate <= '$new_date_out' 
AND NOT EXISTS ( select 1 from payments p where b.bookingid = p.bookingid )
```

Comment: worth mentioning that NOT IN might give you funky results (if not none) when your sub-selection contains null values.

http://sqlinthewild.co.za/index.php/2010/02/18/not-exists-vs-not-in/

Answer (score 0):

Try this as well:

```
SELECT b.bookingid
FROM bookings b
LEFT JOIN payments p ON p.bookingid = b.bookingid
WHERE 'yourdatevariable' BETWEEN b.checkindate AND b.checkoutdate  
    AND p.bookingid IS NULL
```

you can retrieve all the columns that you want and it can help you in the performance as well.